# access elasticsearch data from remote server

Tags: elasticsearch

I am very beginner to Elasticsearch. I read the documentation in elastic.co & running logstash in xx.xx.xx.159 & I have my elasticsearch in x.x.x.111. Now I want to access my elasticsearch data of x.x.x.111 from x.x.x.110 through curl/fiddler and kibana. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One easy fix I can think of is to change your elasticsearch config file so that its hosted on a static ip which belongs to the server it's running on. Now you can access it using kibana by typing "x.x.x.111:5601/app/sense" into a browser on your remote machine.